# Whenever I try to include a JavaScript library like Greensock or Velocity in Tumblr, it doesn't work

Tags: tumblr, cdn, gsap, velocity.js

jQuery works fine in Tumblr. 
I've tried moving this line from header to footer:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
```

I've also tried switching themes multiple times. I've even tried using jQuery's .getScript() to bring in such CDN's from multiple different sources without any luck.

It works FINE when the HTML file I'm using these libraries with are hosted on my own computer.

Comment: It may not work on the theme preview due to CORS, but should work fine on the actual blog. Can you show an example of this not working?

Comment: Open the developer console and load the page, what errors do you see there?